# Trouble returning object through some Callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I am able to get data back but I seem to be failing at getting the result back up through some methods above this:

**car.js**

```
'use strict';

var Q = require('q');
var pg = require('co-pg')(require('pg'));
var config = require('../../models/database-config');

var car = module.exports = {};

car.find = Q.async(function *(id)
{
    var query = 'SELECT id, title, description FROM cars WHERE id = ' + id;

    var connectionResults = yield pg.connectPromise(config.connection);

    var client = connectionResults[0];
    var done = connectionResults[1];

    var result = yield client.queryPromise(query);
    done();

    console.log("value: " + result.rows[0].id);

    return result.rows;
});
```

this returns a valid value for my console.log so I know I'm getting data back.

But now when I try to pass that back up the stack, here I seem to be losing it after this method:

**database.js**

```
module.exports = {
    models: {
        car: _carModel
    },
    find: Q.async(_find)
};

    function _find(carId)
    {
        _carModel.find(carId)
        .then(function(result){
                 console.log('result[0].id: ' + result[0].id);

                return result;
         })
        .catch(function(error){
                console.log("promise error: " + error);
         })
        .done();
    };
```

So this also works, I get a valid value for  console.log('result[0].id: ' + result[0].id);

But now when try to call this function, I lose the result:

**gateway.js**

```
var car = database.find(carId);
                 console.log("car: " + car.id);
...
```

here I get a`'Cannot read property 'id' of undefined]'`

**UPDATE #2**

So I am trying to propagate now the promise up, but still get undefined for the line console.log("returned car data: " + data);  'data' is undefined.

**gateway.js**

```
module.exports = {
    data: function(someData){
        _data = someData;
    },
    find: function(text, result){

        if(!text){
            results(null);
        };

        var endpoint =  _endpoint.replace(/_text/g, text);

         _client.query(endpoint, function(results){

             var cars = [];
             var car;

             for (var i = 0; i < results.docs.length; i++){

                 var carId = results.docs[i].id;

                 car = database.find(carId)
                 .then(function(data){
                         console.log("returned car data: " + data);
                     })
                 .done();

                 cars.push(car);
             }

             result(cars);
        });
    }
```

**database.js**

```
'use strict';
var Q = require('q');

var _obituaryModel = require('../../models/postgreSQL/obituary');

module.exports = {
    models: {
        obituary: _carModel
    },
    find: Q.async(_find)
};

function _find(carId)
{
    _carModel.find(carId)
    .then(function(result){

            console.log('result[0].id: ' + result[0].id);

            return result;
     })
    .catch(function(error){
            console.log("promise error: " + error);
     })
    .done();
};
```

**carModel.js**

```
'use strict';

var Q = require('q');
var pg = require('co-pg')(require('pg'));
var config = require('../../models/database-config');

var car = module.exports = {};

car.find = Q.async(function *(id)
{
    var query = 'SELECT id, title, description FROM cars WHERE id = ' + id;

    var connectionResults = yield pg.connectPromise(config.connection);

    var client = connectionResults[0];
    var done = connectionResults[1];

    var result = yield client.queryPromise(query);
    done();

    console.log("value: " + result.rows[0].id);

    return result.rows;
});
```

Comment: you can't return a value to the outer scope from an asynchronous callback.

Comment: yea I see, and it also appears the result[0].id is called before I try to log car.id because of async also.  So not sure how to handle this

Comment: You have a promise object at your disposal, use it.

Comment: see my latest update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a promise object at your disposal, use it.

In **database.js:**

```
return _obituaryModel.find(carId)
```

and **gateway.js**

```
var car = database.find(carId);
car.then(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: still not getting it working.  I'll post my latest again.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're doing with Q.async, i wonder if that's interfering with this suggestion.

Comment: that is the q middleware to allow your function to promise a result https://github.com/kriskowal/q

Comment: Since your function already returns a promise (after my update), i don't think you need it on _find

Comment: I finally got it.  I'll post the answer shortly.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: sorry I don't need what the car.find = part?

Comment: you said a while ago you said I didn't need something on _find, I wanted to know what you were referring to

Comment: i think i meant you don't need q.async on _find, but don't remember.

Comment: Thanks Kevin I think I recall now.

Answer (score 0):

You can't return data from an asynchronous function.

See here: [How to return value from an asynchronous callback function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847697/how-to-return-value-from-an-asynchronous-callback-function)

Answer (score 0):

You are printing `result[0].id` on the console but reading `result.id` on the actual call:

Try

```
var car = database.find(carId);
             console.log("car: " + car[0].id);
...
```